# Is it possible to create a table from md-list and md-list-item?

Tags: angular-material

I don't want to use angular-material-data-table for this, since it is a different library.

The following does not work:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in todos">
     <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="row">
       <div layout="column">{{item.title}}</div>
       <div layout="column">{{item.description}}</p=div>
     </div>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use `layout-align` attribute with `span` element to get the desired result.

Here is the code.

```
<md-list style="background-color:red">
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <span flex="10">Title</span>
      <span flex="5"></span>
      <span flex="30">Dessciption</span>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="item in todos">
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <span flex="10">{{item.title}}</span>
      <span flex="5"></span>
      <span flex="30">{{item.description}}</span>
    </div>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Working Example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/oLWpPG

Comment: tried this, got an error , md-content' is not a known element ,using this in angular 2.

Comment: answer is applicable to angularJS

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative, based on radio-group, to select row.

```
<md-radio-group>
  <div ng-repeat="" class="row">
    <div flex="" layout="row" layout-padding="" layout-align="start enter">
      <md-radio-button flex="" class="md-primary">
      </md-radio-button>
      <div flex></div>
      <div flex></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-radio-group>
```

Working Example : http://codepen.io/LouisJS/pen/pbwOVB